# iOS UI performance profiling

Tags: performance, user-interface, ios

So far, I have always tested the performance (i.e. "smoothness") of my iOS user interfaces informally, by testing the user interface myself. This is obviously not a very accurate way to profile the performance, so I wondered whether there were some methods / tools that are designed to do this. Are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Instruments tool 'Core Animation' to measure graphics (and thus UI) performance. Mostly in the form of frame rate (which is a formal way of measuring smoothness), but you can also configure it to show overlapping and blended views (which your GPU absolutely hates).

Also, there are some great WWDC sessions available for iOS developers on this topic.

Comment: How many FPS are desirable? I achieve ~50 FPS on the iPhone 4, but this might be quite bad on a 1. generation iPod touch?

Comment: 50 FPS is fine on the 4—the overall refresh rate of the UI is supposed to be around 60 Hz, but anywhere over 30 will look okay. You might want to look for an older device to test your code on.

Comment: When I run the code on an iPod touch 1g, the frame rate is at ~15 fps. It's quite bad but I have no idea how to further improve my code...